# Div growing to more than site width regardless of being set as width:100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to split a div in 2 spaces, each one equally spaced, with a border. This was my attempt:

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;border:0px solid black;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;height:100%">
        <div style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;border:0px solid black;">
            <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;height:100%">
                a
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;border:0px solid black;">
            <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;height:100%">
                b
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This does not work. The outer div overflows the body, so it has >100% width, as opposed to what is stated on the code. Live example at http://viclib.com/screen . How to fix that?

Comment: Works for me… (I was your 999th profile view)

Comment: Congratulations! You are my 999th profile viewer! This is not a joke. Claim your winnings? [Yes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ma37MgOjhtI) / [No](http://gifrific.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Balloons-Falling-Colbert-Report.gif)

Comment: just made it `1000` :), have you tried different `box-sizing` to handle border http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a CSS `outline` instead of a `border`; borders take up space but outlines don't. You can leave everything else the same; just replace the word "border" with "outline".